# .htaccess url rewriting not working while changing php to html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I wish to shorten and clean the `url` that looks like `http://www.example.com/qB/index.html?sch=paramname` to be look like `http://www.example.com/schedule/paramname`

How is it possible ?

I have this rule

```
RewriteRule ^schedule/?$    http://www.example.com/qB/?sch=$1    [NC,L]
```

But its not working.

Comment: Whats not working? Please show all of your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^schedule/([^/]*)/?$ /qB/index.html?sch=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @HarshArora try now?